# Value for each row in Pascal Triangle - Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

In the following code:

```
def pascal_row(row):
    if row == 0:
        return [1]
    previous_row = pascal_row(row - 1)
    pairs = zip(previous_row[:-1], previous_row[1:])
    return [1] + map(sum, pairs) + [1]
```

if I `print (pascal_row(5))`, it returns `[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]` which is the correct solution.

This is a homework assignment where we need to use recursion, and cannot use any loops or `zip`.

Could someone please help me convert it accordingly? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: `sliding_sum(A) = [A[0] + A[1]] + sliding_sum(A[1:])`

Comment: @georg I don't follow, I'm sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different recursive function `sliding_sum` in order to calculate the pairwise sum for the previous row.  Then, just append `[1]` on either end.

```
def sliding_sum(someList):
    if len(someList) == 1:
        return []
    return [someList[0] + someList[1]] + sliding_sum(someList[1:])

def pascal_row(row):
    if row == 0:
        return [1]
    previous_row = pascal_row(row-1)
    new_row = [1] + sliding_sum(previous_row) + [1]
    return new_row

for i in range(6):
    print pascal_row(i)
```

## Output

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution involving a helper function:

```
def pascal_row(row):
    if row == 0:
        return [1]
    return _pascal_row(row, 0, [1])

def _pascal_row(target_row, current_row, res):
    if target_row == current_row:
        return res
    else:
        res = [1] + [res[i] + res[i+1] for i in xrange(len(res) - 1)] + [1]
        return _pascal_row(target_row, current_row + 1, res)

print pascal_row(5) # [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
```